# Can I still wear socks for each prayer?

Tags: wudu, incontinence

If I’m suffering from farts continuously and if I’m wearing socks, do i have to take off my socks every time I make wudu and wear it again or can I just wipe over it like how you would normally do when you wanna make wudu with socks on even if you feel sometime during the wudu or after the wudu?

Answer (score -1):

In Islamic tradition, there is a concept known as masah, which refers to the act of wiping over certain types of footwear during wudu, instead of washing the feet. This practice is based on certain Hadith, or sayings attributed to the Prophet Muhammad. However, there is considerable variation and disagreement among Muslim scholars about the specifics of this practice, including when it can be done, what types of footwear it applies to, and under what circumstances it is valid.

Some scholars hold that masah can only be done if the socks (or other footwear) were put on after a complete wudu, and that one must remove and wash the feet in the event of a major impurity (such as passing gas), while others are more lenient.

However, in my opinion, one of the fundamental values of any religious or moral system should be compassion and consideration for human needs and limitations. If you're suffering from a medical condition that makes it difficult or uncomfortable to remove your socks for wudu, I would hope that any reasonable interpretation of Islamic law would take that into account.